# Are special characters used in Rich Text Fields configurable? Can I create new ones to the list?

Tags: cme

I need to add extra special characters to the list provided within Rich Text Fields, is this possible and if so how should it be done please?

Comment: Good question--this, CSS styles, and custom nodes are probably the main three questions I see when RTF functionality comes up in training or implementations.

Comment: Hi Richard, could you specify the Tridion version on your questions please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/task_270BA8BF4EE8477A80B7D2BED2B8BD82) you can add characters to a file named "SpecialCharacters.xml", stored under "\Tridion\web\WebUI\Models\CME\Configuration".

You need to specify several attributes for the character to be displayed:

```
<Entries>
  <Entry>       
    <Value>string or character</Value>
    <Description>Generic Description</Description>
    <Description lang="User Language ID 1">Description for User Language 1</Description>
    <Description lang="User Language ID 2">Description for User Language 2</Description>
  </Entry>
</Entries>
```